# cache result from dplyr database backend

Tags: sql, r, caching, dplyr

I'm using `dplyr`'s database backend on an AWS Redshift database. And because some queries are taking rather forever to return I would like to cache them. I know the underlying data won't change so if the query doesn't change then neither will the result set.

An approach I've taken elsewhere to accomplish this is

- hash the query string
- save the result of the query to a `{hash}.rds` file
- on the next run of the script, if the hash hasn't changed, read the result from disk, otherwise re-run the query

I've been trying the same approach with `dplyr`. Unfortunately the SQL query strings that dplyr generates change even if the operations stay the same:

```
df %>%
  select(week, person_id) %>%
  group_by(person_id) %>%
  mutate(weeks_active = n()) %>%
  arrange(weeks_active) %>% 
  dplyr::sql_render()
```

generates

```
<SQL> SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "week", "person_id", COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "person_id") AS "weeks_active"
FROM (SELECT "week" AS "week", "person_id" AS "person_id"
FROM "fct_person_week") "zznunjjdwe") "ltyyfmiahu"
ORDER BY "weeks_active"
```

on the first run and

```
<SQL> SELECT *
FROM (SELECT "week", "person_id", COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY "person_id") AS "weeks_active"
FROM (SELECT "week" AS "week", "person_id" AS "person_id"
FROM "fct_person_week") "stxupavckd") "oaknuxjexc"
ORDER BY "weeks_active"
```

on the second. Is there any way to keep the table aliases fixed? Are there other summaries of the query that will be identical over multiple runs? Or should I look into other ways of caching this?

Comment: can you set a seed of some sort for the hash key?

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to use `compute()` to create a temporary table.  Another option would be to take the resulting SQL and convert it into a View, so the R developer simply calls it as a table name.